# deploy ruby on rails to aws using Elastic Beanstalk error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using  Elastic Beanstalk to deploy ruby on rails application to aws. im following the instruction on this website.

[Deploying a Rails Application to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ruby-rails-tutorial.html)

but WHEN i get to step to deploy the application i get an error

[image]

This image from eb-activity.log
[image]

[image]

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
gem 'spring'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'devise', '~>4.2'
gem 'toastr-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.6'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~>5.1.0'
gem 'aws-sdk','~> 2.8'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.4'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'ransack', '~> 1.7'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.11.1'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.17.1'
gem 'stripe', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'rails-assets-card', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'omniauth-stripe-connect', '~> 2.10.0'
gem 'chartkick', '~> 2.2.4'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
gem 'yaml_db'
gem 'vider'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.8.1'
```

[image]

Comment: make sure `bundle install` in localhost and is't puma or passenger server ?

Comment: @7urkm3n yes I have bundle install inside my folder directory, im using gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'

Comment: what about EB, is Puma or Passenger ? make sure to choose Puma 2.4. also can u post gemfile

Comment: @7urkm3n I did add gemfile to the question . for the EB it cant be changed to puma in the console and by default it sets to Passenger. i create new environment using eb cli I select  Puma 2.4 then I run through error, i have image of the error edit to the question and  I followed this link

Comment: @7urkm3n here is the link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938155/right-way-to-deploy-rails-puma-postgres-app-to-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: take a look this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpAyBX2DNTw&list=PL5vDt5AALlRdd2d_qXhZpTJOFJA4fiuvX&index=2

Answer (score 1):

The relevant error is:

```
Installing nokogiri 1.8.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

nokogiri 1.8.1 has security vulnerabilities so it is a very good idea to upgrade to the latest version, which is 1.8.3. This also might have the side effect of fixing the build error you are seeing, so it is worth a shot.

On your development machine, upgrade nokogiri like this:

```
bundle update --conservative nokogiri
```

Then commit the Gemfile.lock, push and redeploy.

If that still doesn't work, you may simply not have enough memory on the server to compile the nokogiri extensions. See this question: [ElasticBeanstalk - Rails Nokogiri Deployment Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945708/elasticbeanstalk-rails-nokogiri-deployment-issue)

Or search for "nokogiri elastic beanstalk" for more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nokogiri+elastic+beanstalk

Comment: I believe @Matt Brictson has the right answer - the `Cannot allocate memory` error in `eb-activity.log` indicates that your instance is too small. Try using a bigger instance (along with the latest version of Nokogiri) and the problem should go away.